# Adding Integers in muti-line list

Tags: python, computer-science

```
locations = ("Bowling Den", "Krazy Bowl", "City Bowl", "Top Bowling", "PinBowl")
games = ("10-Pin", "5-Pin", "Candlepin")
gamesPlayed = [[100, 250, 200],
               [500, 600, 700],
               [200, 225, 230],
               [120, 520, 500],
               [405, 60, 255]]
```

I'm trying to refer to column 0, 1 and 2 of gamesPlayed for:

```
print ("10-Pin", *total amount in column*)
print ("5-Pin", *total amount in column*)
print ("CandlePin", *total amount in column*)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Pls. refer to the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section on how to ask questions here. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Fix formatting and indent

Answer (score 1):

Use sum() on a list comprehension:

```
print ("10-Pin",    sum(row[0] for row in gamesPlayed)) 
print ("5-Pin",     sum(row[1] for row in gamesPlayed))
print ("CandlePin", sum(row[2] for row in gamesPlayed))
```

output:

```
10-Pin 1325
5-Pin 1655
CandlePin 1885
```